# Dynamically Filter a Dynamically generated list based on id and textbox text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

WORKING

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                $('#table-repeat-data').remove();
                                setInterval(update_powerstatus, 2000);  
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                var sortarrows = '<img src={% static "icons/asc.png" %}>'
                                $('#table_name').append("<table class='tablesorter table' id='table-repeat-data' data-sortable><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name" +sortarrows+ "</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>Command Status</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState " +sortarrows+ "</b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands</b></th></tr></thead><tbody class='list'>");
                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) { 
                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn1(this)" class="btn btn-success" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" onClick="Reset_send(this)" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM"  id="ResetVM" onClick="powerOff_send(this)" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td valign="center" width="35%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '" class="name">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td valign="center" width="35%" id="status' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][3] + '</td><td valign="center" width="10%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + on + '</td><td valign="center" width="20%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td valign="center" width="35%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '" class="name" >' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td valign="center" width="35%" id="status' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][3] + '</td><td valign="center" width="10%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + off + '</td><td valign="center" width="20%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }


                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }

                    });
                    return false;

            }); 
            $("#table-repeat-data").tablesorter();             
        });

function update_powerstatus(){

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'

                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {


                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn_send(this)" class="btn btn-success" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" onClick="powerOff_send(this)" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM" id="ResetVM" onClick="Reset_send(this)" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){           
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';
                                        var stat_message_id = 'status' + json.vmlist[index][2];
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(stat_message_id).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][3];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = on + "<font color='white'>1</font>";
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }else{
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';   
                                        var stat_message_id = 'status' + json.vmlist[index][2];
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(stat_message_id).innerHTML =  json.vmlist[index][3];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = off + "<font color='white'>0</font>";
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
var $rows = $("#table-repeat-data tr"),
    $filter = $("#filter");

$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filterText = $filter.val().toLowerCase();
    $rows.each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.toggle($row.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
    });
});
 $("#table-repeat-data").tablesorter();    
}
```

I tried the answer provided by zord, I still call it inside of a looping function so that the values will update as they update in the dynamic table. To pre-answer any questions I have tried it outside of the looping function and the same thing happens. When I use the JS fiddle it works, however when I use it on mine it only filters tables when there are 0 tables with what is typed in the box. It is not recognizing the VM names in the table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to dynamically hide table rows tags that are passed to a function as a list. Then you loop through this list and compare lowercase letters typed in the textbox name vmfilter if the letters typed in the text box match the name it will hide all other tables without that name.

for example our list of vm names is

```
(test 1, test3vm, highlife, millerlight, beer, nitromilk stout)
```

***and a user types 'm'***

only **test3vm, millerlight, and nitromilk** will show because they have an m. I also need to convert the list names to lower as it loops.

I will preface this with I really suck at JavaScript to my attempt is only half complete and probably way out to lunch.. This function is started after all the data has been properly displayed and runs on a 200ms interval

This is my attempt but it doesn't actually work it will hide some of the  fields but it doesn't reconstruct them correctly, and it doesn't match correctly. I need it to remove the fields because there is still table white space when it removes them.

```
function checkForMatch(string,array){
    var arrKeys = array.length;
    var match = false;
    var patt;
        for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
         patt=new RegExp(" "+array[index][0].toLowerCase()+" ");
         if(patt.test(string)){
           document.getElementById(array[index][0]).style.visibility = "visible";
           console.log(string);
           console.log(array[index][0].toLowerCase());
          }else{
            console.log(array[index][0].toLowerCase());
            console.log(string);
            document.getElementById(array[index][0]).style.visibility = "hidden";
          }

        }
}

function vm_filter_name(vmlist){

    var name = $('#vmfilter').val().toLowerCase();
    if(name == ''){
        for (var index = 0; index < vmlist.length; index++) {
         document.getElementById(vmlist[index][0]).style.visibility = "visible";
        }

    }else{
            checkForMatch(name, vmlist);    
    }

}

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                $('#table-repeat-data').remove();
                                setInterval(update_powerstatus, 2000);  
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                $('#table_name').append("<table class='table' id='table-repeat-data' data-sortable><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>Command Status</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");
                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) { 
                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn1(this)" class="btn btn-success" value="' + json.vmlist[index][5] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" onClick="Reset_send(this)" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][6] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM"  id="ResetVM" onClick="powerOff_send(this)" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][7] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][8] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr id="' + json.vmlist[index][0]+ '"><td valign="center" width="40%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td valign="center" width="35%" id="status' + json.vmlist[index][9] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][10] + '</td><td valign="center" width="5%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][11] + '1">' + on + '</td><td valign="center" width="20%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][12] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr id="' + json.vmlist[index][0]+ '"><td valign="center" width="40%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td valign="center" width="35%" id="status' + json.vmlist[index][13] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][14] + '</td><td valign="center" width="5%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][15] + '1">' + off + '</td><td valign="center" width="20%" id="' + json.vmlist[index][16] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }


                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }

                    });
                    return false;
            });              
        });
function update_powerstatus(){

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'

                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    setInterval(vm_filter_name(json.vmlist), 150);
                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn_send(this)" class="btn btn-success" value="' + json.vmlist[index][17] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" onClick="powerOff_send(this)" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][18] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM" id="ResetVM" onClick="Reset_send(this)" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][19] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][20] == 'poweredOn'){          
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][21] + '1';
                                        var stat_message_id = 'status' + json.vmlist[index][22];
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(stat_message_id).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][23];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = on;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][24]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }else{
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][25] + '1';  
                                        var stat_message_id = 'status' + json.vmlist[index][26];
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(stat_message_id).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][27];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = off;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][28]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of table row filtering. I hope this helps.

You can try it out here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdg04yqs/).

```
var $rows = $("#table tr"),
    $filter = $("#filter");

$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filterText = $filter.val().toLowerCase();
    $rows.each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.toggle($row.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
    });
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle works correctly but it doesn't work on mine, it will only hide the rows when none exist with the string entered. For example if i type xxyss they will all disappear but if i type the unique name of one none will disappear. I'm reinitializing the function inside my looping update because it is dynamic data, I've tried inside that outside that everywhere and still no go.

Comment: @Grant: Do you reinitialize the outside variables to? Also, can you make a jsfiddle with your code, so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I can't because all of the vars and data are dynamic from Django I wouldn't even begin to know how to make a fiddle for it.

Comment: the data is on a looping function once I build the inital html I use the looping function to update the innerHTML and it loops every second.